# Signing of binary by someone else

Tags: xcode, flash, flash-builder

I am trying to figure out if I am in a potential bind here.  I am having someone else develop my app and I have given them complete access to my developer account to create the certificates to build the binary.  I have uploaded the binary using the Application Loader and it it now waiting for review by Apple.  My question is when it comes time to update the app, will I be able to do so without using the programmer who signed the certificate?  When I become competent I'd like to do this myself but I'm clearly not there yet. I don't want to be in a situation where I have to keep going back to the same programmer to do the smallest thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, provided you:

- Have them send you the signing assets as described in "Exporting Your Code Signing Assets to Your File System" in the Xcode documentation. Note that they will still be able to sign using your key.
- Have them send you the original project, obviously.

Once you part ways with them you should change the passwords of any accounts they've been given access to, like Apple ID and iTunes Connect.

At a later date, or as a last resort, you can create new signing assets as described in "Reset You Signing and Provisioning Assets..." in the Tools Workflow Guide.

So, most important going forward, they must not have access to any Apple accounts belonging to you.